# Is there any way to duplicate bones radially?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, mirror

I'm building an object that has radial symmetry, and it's armature would have the same symmetry. Is there any way to automatically duplicate bones radially after building the initial piece, or do I simply have to duplicate and position by hand?

Comment: If you would like to see a beginner video tutorial series this is one ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lY6KPrc4uMw&list=PLda3VoSoc_TR7X7wfblBGiRz-bvhKpGkS ... If you browse titles you might look for ... center of rotation ... armature bones ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an idea... you can dupliface the armature:

[image]

Here I used a cylinder: the number of faces will make the radial distribution.

Once original armature is ok, you need:

- to select the cylinder and make duplicate real
- to select the duplicated armature and make them single user
- then join them:

[image]

Though, I don't think there is a mean to duplicate the eventually created animation on the original armature by this way...

Answer (score 0):

[image]

- Yes.  You can duplicate radially in two steps.
- Duplicate <kbd>Shift D</kbd>and Rotate <kbd>r</kbd>.
- Edit Mode with a single armature.
- You know the radial center.  Place 3D cursor to radial center.
- Change center of rotation to 3D cursor.  This is indicated with arrow in image.
- Duplicate correct bone, or bone sequence. Rotate in the appropriate plane a number of degrees which can be typed such as precise 30.
- The cyan bones have been specified as not connected to the parent.
- Duplication with <kbd>Shift D</kbd>
  When finished change your center of rotation back to your desired settings
- You could place a temporary cylinder for casual eyeball inspection or snap the cursor to locations on the cylinder.  See Blender snapping capabilities.
- Please know I am at this point giving high level suggestions and not menu names or keystrokes.  The video series suggested above will save you time and energy.

Comment: I actually was already doing this when I posted the question, but @lemon's more automated solution was what I was looking for.